# Is "intelligence" a countable noun?

Tags: countability

All my "learner's dictionaries" - Oxford, Cambridge, and Longman- say that "intelligence" is an uncountable noun which means " the ability to learn, understand, and think in a logical way about something" (and I should say that I have no access to OED).However, I came across "AN intelligence" while reading an article titled "Clever Hans" which was about an intelligent horse:

> Hans the horse was bought in 1900 by Wilhelm von Osten, a retired German schoolmaster, who was convinced that animals had an intelligence equal to that of humans.

My question is, if "intelligence" can be used as a countable noun, does it differ in meaning from "intelligence" as an uncountable noun?

Comment: Good question +1. It seems authors do use *an intelligence* in some rare cases. *"The test of **a first-rate intelligence** is the ability to hold two opposed ideas in the mind at the same time, and still retain the ability to function"" - F. Scott Fitzgerald*

Answer (score 5):

*Intelligence* is not being used as a countable noun in *Clever Hans*. There's some information ellipted; read the sentence like this:

> ... animals had an *amount or degree of* intelligence equal to that of humans.

Here, *intelligence* is qualifiable but not quantifiable.

However, it is possible to use *intelligence* as a countable noun, though this usage is less common. See [definition 1.1 here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/intelligence) and [definition 2 here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intelligence). A common usage of this involves a countable but heterogeneous group of either intelligent minds or types of mental processing. For example:

- There are many different types of intelligence. (Here *intelligence* means *efficacious manner of thinking*.)
- Space exploration might discover intelligences other than our own. (Here *intelligence* means *conscious mind or being*.)

Comment: That's a good point. I had never thought some information might have been left out delibrately by the author.